# php to html .htaccess Help

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following code in the my .htaccess file and the top Rewrite works fine the bottem one does not I know why but I dont kno how to fix it.

Its seeing RewriteRule **^([^/]*).html** index.php?p=order&course_id=$1 [L] as the top rewrite command becuase of the hightlighed part and i dont want to put it in a dir

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^([^/.]+).html
>   index.php?p=$1 [L]
>
> ```
> index.php?p=about_us
> ```
>
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html
>   index.php?p=order&course_id=$1 [L]

```
 index.php?p=order&course_id=5
```

Thank you,

Comment: Not sure I get this rught because LHS condition for both of your rules is same `^([^/]+).html` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give example urls that should match the pattern block and what you would like them to be rewritten to? That would be very helpful.

One thing I notice is that your first regexp you test if you match the pattern block with a `+` which means 1 or more times and the second one you check it with a `*` which means 0 or more so I don't think the second one will ever be called, although I am very new to regexps but it is just something I noticed.

These are very helpful resources for me:

http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php

http://forum.modrewrite.com/

Comment: @Gully okay so you want domain.com/about_us to turn into domain.com/index.php?p=about_us I think but what about the second one?

Answer (score 0):

From the example of the urls you would be using, this should work:

```
# http://website.com/about_us/ rewrites to /index.php?p=about_us
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]

# http://website.com/order/12/ rewrites to /index.php?p=order&course_id=12
RewriteRule ^order/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=order&course_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The second Rewrite might be:

```
# http://website.com/order/12/ rewrites to /index.php?p=order&course_id=12
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&course_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Depending on your page structure.